# How does QEMU risc-v put FDT address in register a1?

Tags: qemu, riscv

From RISC-V OpenSBI's source code and documents, in OpenSBI firmware `a1` preserves FDT address from the prior booting stage, which I guess is QEMU if the following command is used to boot OpenSBI firmware:

```
qemu-system-riscv64 -M virt -m 256M -nographic -bios build/platform/generic/firmware/fw_payload.bin
```

and OpenSBI firmware is built with

```
make PLATFORM=generic CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-linux-gnu-
```

`fw_base.S` in OpenSBI's source code will use the value of `a1` to invoke `fw_platform_init`, which assumes `a1` contains the FDT address.

My question is when and how `a1` is set before `fw_base.S`？

Answer (score 1):

`a1` is set by function `riscv_setup_rom_reset_vec(...)` which in `qemu/hw/riscv/boot.c` inserts some instructions to set FDT address:

```c
    /* reset vector */
    uint32_t reset_vec[10] = {
        0x00000297,                  /* 1:  auipc  t0, %pcrel_hi(fw_dyn) */
        0x02828613,                  /*     addi   a2, t0, %pcrel_lo(1b) */
        0xf1402573,                  /*     csrr   a0, mhartid  */
        0,
        0,
        0x00028067,                  /*     jr     t0 */
        start_addr,                  /* start: .dword */
        start_addr_hi32,
        fdt_load_addr,               /* fdt_laddr: .dword */
        0x00000000,
                                     /* fw_dyn: */
    };
    if (riscv_is_32bit(harts)) {
        reset_vec[3] = 0x0202a583;   /*     lw     a1, 32(t0) */
        reset_vec[4] = 0x0182a283;   /*     lw     t0, 24(t0) */
    } else {
        reset_vec[3] = 0x0202b583;   /*     ld     a1, 32(t0) */
        reset_vec[4] = 0x0182b283;   /*     ld     t0, 24(t0) */
    }
```

When qemu runs, it will first jump to `0x1000` to execute these instructions and then jump to `_start`.